# Trying to find substrings in large string

Tags: python, dna-sequence

Given this string

```
dna3 = "CATGTAATAGATGAATGACTGATAGATATGCTTGTATGCTATGAAAATGTGAAATGACCC"
```

the following code should print the following 4 substrings.

```
ATGTAA
ATGAATGACTGATAG
ATGCTATGA
ATGTGA
```

However, it is printing the following:

```
ATGTAA
ATGAATGACTGATAG
ATGACTGATAGATATGCTTGTATGCTATGAAAATGTGAAATGACCC
ATGCTTGTATGCTATGAAAATGTGAAATGACCC
ATGCTATGA
ATGAAAATGTGA
ATGTGA
ATGACCC
None
```

May someone please help me figure this out. Thank you.

```
def findStopIndex(dna,index):

    stop1 = dna.find("tga",index)
    if(stop1 == -1 or (stop1-index) % 3 != 0):
        stop1 = len(dna)

    stop2 = dna.find("taa",index)
    if(stop2 == -1 or (stop2-index) % 3 != 0):
        stop2 = len(dna)

    stop3 = dna.find("tag",index)
    if(stop3 == -1 or (stop3-index) % 3 != 0):
        stop3 = len(dna)

    return min(stop1, min(stop2,stop3))  

def printAll(dna):
    gene = None
    start = 0
    while(True):
        loc = dna.find("atg", start)
        if(loc == -1):break
        stop = findStopIndex(dna,loc+3)
        gene = dna[loc:stop+3]
        print gene.upper()
        start = loc + 3


print printAll(dna3.lower())
```

Comment: To debug this I would print the values of index, stop1, stop2 and stop3. I suspect you will then see that the one of values is not what you expectd.

Comment: `min` can be used with multiple arguments: `min(stop1, stop2, stop3)`.

Comment: `if` and `while` are no functions, therefore the parentheses are unnecessary.

Comment: Your problem is: you have set `stop1 = len(dna)` for the wrong case.

Comment: I do not know for sure (not my field) but I strongly suspect that there is a Python library for the manipulation of DNA strings. When they get large (millions/billions of bases) then rolling your own Python will be hugely inefficient compared to using an optimized library with primitive operations written in a non-interpreted language.

Comment: in your printAll(dna) function, you can change start = loc + 3 to start = loc + len(gene) + 3. Then it will search from where the previous gene has ended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may need some additional informations regarding DNA structure. From what you described, it feels like the substrings **can't overlap each other**. In this case, you need to replace `start = loc + 3` by `start = stop + 3` (the characters seem to be **grouped 3 by 3**, also based and what you described).

Finally, you don't need the `print` in `print printAll(dna3.lower())`, since it shows the `None` at the end of your result set (the function doesn't have a return value).

With those modifications, my output is :

```
ATGTAA
ATGAATGACTGATAG
ATGCTTGTATGCTATGAAAATGTGAAATGACCC
```

Hope it'll be helpful.

Comment: He want to search all substrings. If you do `start = stop + 3`, you will skip over some substrings

Comment: @julivico the stop index returned is the index of the **first** character of the 3 character group, hence my +3. This is also why he prints `dna[loc:stop+3]`.

Comment: Look at the output `ATGAATGACTGATAG`. There is `ATG` in this string. If you use `stop + 3`, you will skip it.

Comment: @julivico nope, check my output, I have it =)

Comment: Than you! start = stop + 3 is what fixed it. You are correct in that the substrings should not overlap. Again, many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could have explained it a bit better but to get what you want to get you cannot return the min like that or when you do you have to treat it otherwise. The long chains you are getting is because you are returning '60' which is the length of the whole sequence. I modified the code a bit and it does only pick up sequences that end in one of 'tga', 'taa', or 'tag'.

```
def findStopIndex(dna, index):
    stop1 = dna.find("tga", index)
    if (stop1 == -1 or (stop1 - index) % 3 != 0):
        stop1 = len(dna)
    stop2 = dna.find("taa", index)
    if (stop2 == -1 or (stop2 - index) % 3 != 0):
        stop2 = len(dna)
    stop3 = dna.find("tag", index)
    if (stop3 == -1 or (stop3 - index) % 3 != 0):
        stop3 = len(dna)
    end_sequence = min(stop1, stop2, stop3)if min(stop1, stop2, stop3) < 60 else None
    return end_sequence

def printAll(dna):
    start = 0
    while True:
        loc = dna.find("atg", start)
        if loc == -1:
            break
        stop = findStopIndex(dna, loc + 3)
        if stop:
            gene = dna[loc:stop+3]
            print(gene.upper())
        start = loc + 3
    return

printAll(dna3.lower())
```

**Outputs:**

```
ATGTAA
ATGAATGACTGATAG
ATGCTATGA
ATGAAAATGTGA
ATGTGA
```

Comment: remove the `print` in `print(printAll(dna3.lower()))` will remove the output `None`. The function `printAll` returns nothing (or None).

Comment: @julivico: yeah, i saw 3kt's answer and then it hit me too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

changes:

1) min should use "key=int" otherwise the sort will be done as string...

```
return min(stop1,stop2,stop3, key=int)
```

2) break was replaced with exit to avoid another loop with while

Answer (score 0):

change start = loc + 3 to
start = loc +len(gene)+ 3

```
def findStopIndex(dna,index):

    stop1 = dna.find("tga",index)
    if(stop1 == -1 or (stop1-index) % 3 != 0):
        stop1 = len(dna)

    stop2 = dna.find("taa",index)
    if(stop2 == -1 or (stop2-index) % 3 != 0):
        stop2 = len(dna)

    stop3 = dna.find("tag",index)
    if(stop3 == -1 or (stop3-index) % 3 != 0):
        stop3 = len(dna)

    return min(stop1, min(stop2,stop3))

def printAll(dna):
    gene = None
    start = 0
    while(True):
        loc = dna.find("atg", start)
        if(loc == -1):break
        stop = findStopIndex(dna,loc+3)
        gene = dna[loc:stop+3]
        print gene.upper()
        start = loc +len(gene)+ 3

dna3 = "CATGTAATAGATGAATGACTGATAGATATGCTTGTATGCTATGAAAATGTGAAATGACCC"
printAll(dna3.lower())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you don't want the results, that lead to printing the string till the end, so you have to rule these cases out.
And better use a for-loop for all endings:

```
def findStopIndex(dna, index):
    stops = []
    for tag in ["TGA", "TAA", "TAG"]:
        stop = dna.find(tag, index)
        if stop >= 0 and (stop - index) % 3 == 0:
            stops.append(stop)
    return min(stops)

def printAll(dna):
    dna = dna.upper()
    start = 0
    while True:
        loc = dna.find("ATG", start)
        if loc == -1:
            break
        try:
            stop = findStopIndex(dna, loc + 3)
        except ValueError:
            # no ending found
            pass
        else:
            print(dna[loc:stop+3])
        start = loc + 3

printAll(dna3)
```

But I think, what you really want, is to find one of TGA, TAA and TAG even if in between TGA occurs on a position, that is not divisible by 3. This can be done by regular expressions:

```
import re

def printAll(dna):
    dna = dna.upper()
    start = 0
    while True:
        mtch = re.search("ATG(...)*?(TGA|TAA|TAG)", dna[start:])
        if not mtch:
            break
        print(mtch.group())
        start += mtch.start() + 3

printAll(dna3)
```

and results in two more occurances:

```
ATGTAA
ATGAATGACTGA
ATGACTGATAGATATGCTTGTATGCTATGA
ATGCTTGTATGCTATGAAAATGTGAAATGA
ATGCTATGA
ATGAAAATGTGA
ATGTGA
```